# Distance program throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in line 19

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a program to compute the distance between two points for practice, and the compiler is throwing an out of bounds exception on line 19.  From what I can see, the array settings don't seem to be out of bounds, however they obviously are.  Not sure how to proceed at this point.  Here is the code in question:

```
public class Distance {
private java.awt.Point point0, point1;


   public Distance(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) {  
     point0 = new java.awt.Point(x0, y0); 
     point1 = new java.awt.Point(x1, y1);
   }

   public void printDistance() {
     System.out.println("Distance between " + point0 + " and " + point1
                     + " is " + point0.distance(point1));   
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {                 
     Distance dist = new Distance(                          
              intValue(args[0]), intValue(args[1]), // this is the error line //
              intValue(args[2]), intValue(args[3]));
     dist.printDistance();
   }

   private static int intValue(String data) {
     return Integer.parseInt(data);
   }
 }
```

Comment: How are you setting the application arguments? And what's `args` length?

Comment: Well, what happens when you print `args.length`? Or, even better, just print `Arrays.toString(args)` to see what `args` really contains.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value you are passing as arguement.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not passing any command line arguments. Run this application through a command line or find a section to pass these arguments in your IDE.

Comment: Hrm.  I attempted to run it on the CLI in Windows 7, by the following command, and I get an error:   could not find or load main class instance.

I run it by typing: java Distance 0 3 4 1

Think if I add a couple scanner lines in the program prompting for input, it would work?